# Cascade of deletes ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can add a cascade of deletes that will remove Profile, TodoList, and TodoItem rows for any User removed.

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :todo_lists
  has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items
  validates :username, presence: true
  end
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user

     validates :first_name, presence: true
     validates :last_name, presence: true

     validates :gender, inclusion: %w(male female)

     validate :first_and_last
     validate :male_Sue


    def first_and_last
      if (first_name.nil? and last_name.nil?)
        errors.add(:base, "Specify a first or a last.")
      end
    end

    def male_Sue
      if (first_name == "Sue" and gender == "male")
        errors.add(:base, "we are prevent male by name Sue.")
      end
    end
  end
```

TodoList Model:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
    default_scope { order :list_due_date }
  end
```

TodoItem Model:

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list

  default_scope {order :due_date }
end
```

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I guess adding `dependent: :destroy` will do.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

*`has_many`, `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations support the `:dependent` option. This allows you to specify that associated records should be deleted when the owner is deleted*

By using `dependent: :destroy` on your association in the User class, anytime you destroy a User, all associated objects to that instance gets destroyed as well.

You can [check this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Deleting+from+associations) for more information.